# No muestra Alert cuando esta dentro de un CompletableFuture (JAVA)

Tags: java, java-ee, javafx, java-8

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
Alert alert;
String resultado;

resultado = "incompleto";
CompletableFuture <String> futureSupplyAsync = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    Future <String> future = executor.submit(new MiMetodo());
    try {
        resultado = future.get();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        resultado = "incompleto";
    }
    return resultado;
}, executor);

futureSupplyAsync.whenCompleteAsync((s, e) -> {
    executor.shutdown();
    if (resultado == "completo") {
        System.out.println("completo todo ok");
        alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Notificación");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Finalizo el proceso correctamente");
        alert.showAndWait();
    } else {
        System.out.println("paso un error");
        alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Atencion");
        alert.setHeaderText("Hubo un error al procesar informacion.");
        alert.setContentText("Hubo un error");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
});
```

El código funciona, cuando evalúa `resultado` da `true`, y por consola sale "completo todo ok", pero la alerta no la muestra.
Que podria estar sucediendo a mi codigo?

Answer (score 0):

No conozco la clase *CompletableFuture* pero intuyo que puede ser un problema con los hilos.

Puedes meter el bloque del *alert* en un *try-catch* y usar `e.printStackTrace();` (sólo), para ver detalles del problema.

Reemplaza la línea:

```
alert.showAndWait();
```

por esta otra:

```
Platform.runLater(alert::showAndWait);
```

Puedes consultar la siguiente respuesta (en inglés) que habla de problemas con *Alert* en entornos multihilo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43237169/3919660